# I want to search for the name and it will show the whole name

Tags: plsql

I want to search the name and it will show the whole name:

```
VARIABLE name
VARCHAR2(15) 
SET AUTOPRINT ON 
DECLARE 
   v_me VARCHAR2(10) 
   v_me myname.fname%TYPE :=&fname; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT fname|| ' ' || lname 
      INTO :name 
   FROM myname 
   WHERE fname = v_me; 
END; 
/
```

When I run it the error was **Encountered the symbol**

Comment: I assume you are running this in Oracle's SQL\*Plus. You can't use SQL\*Plus variables inside a PL/SQL block like that. There is no PL/SQL variable `:name` that's why you get an error. You are also defining the variable `v_me` twice with different data types.

Comment: what should i do? what is the correct code for that?

Comment: I also tried v_me varchar(10):= &fname; then it says that i should declare the name that I searched